# Put UICollectionViewCell into UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `LBTAComponents` pod 
this is a pod that makes easier to work with `UICollectionView` 
without any need to register anything and provides a super simple anchoring system ... and in the first project I've got two days ago I decided to use this framework
but now I have a problem in one of `uicollectionviewCells` I need another `collectionview` that I can fill with items then I need it to be scrollable horizontally

```
import LBTAComponents
import UIKit

class ProductCell: DatasourceCell {
    let cellId = "cellid"
    let collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .black
        return cv
    }()

    override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

        ProductCell.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = frame
        collectionView.register(UICollectionView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

}

extension ProductCell : UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        return cell
    }

}
```

`datasourceCell` is equal to `UICollectionViewCell` in this pod.

and now I am getting this ERROR :

```
instance member 'addsubview' cannot be used on type uiview did you use the value of this type instead?
```

could you please help me?

I tried to use `self.addSubview(collectionView)`

but I got another error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiUlc.png)

Comment: Why are you using a 3rd party to do that? It can be easily achieved using UICollectionView. 3rd party might be adding more complexity to it.

Comment: you know that became a chalenge for me but i think i will start the traditional way...

Comment: And what is the traditional way?

Comment: UicollectionView

Comment: So have you achieved it using UICollectionView?

Comment: actually i am new to programming i have an app that shoud have different rows with Different sizes and inside each of them i need a collection view i am wondering should i use table view or collection view for Rows?

Comment: If your requirement is satisfied with UITableView you can use it until unless you require any custom layout. Dynamic height rows can be handles using UITableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` containing a `UICollectionView`.

***Example:***

**1. View Hierarchy**

[image]

**2. `UIViewController` containing `UITableView`**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tcell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            return 120
        }
        else
        {
            return 150
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Custom `UITableViewCell` containing `UICollectionView`**

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ccell", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**4. Output Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

addsubview is an instance method, not a class method. So you should use:

```
self.addSubview(collectionView)
```

instead of:

```
ProductCell.addSubview(collectionView)
```

Comment: i tried to use this but i will get another error i will put